# i created my react app and changed two files in it. now the browser shows error: enoent

Tags: reactjs

[this is the browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/081ut.png)

this my first app i created and changed two files to get the hang of it. now the browser shows a common error:enoent...
i tried thrice already but nothing seems to be working.

this is index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld/>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is the helloworld,js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="helloContainer">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Comment: Hey @MRD. Your file name is `helloworld.js` and you are importing it as `HelloWorld`. Do rename the file name at one place.

Comment: Then, `helloworld.js` may be something entirely different than `helloworld,js` as per question body.

Comment: i tried that yash. its still not working. i could be missing something very small i just know it

Comment: imports are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Imports are case sensitive, try `import HelloWorld from './helloworld'`

Comment: i tried that now.still not working. i think it could be configuration or some extension im missing?

Comment: Make sure your webpack.config.json is properly configured but it should be ok, are you sure that helloworld file is the same folder?